# Scikit learn - customizing cost function

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I kind of have some idea how to do it in python but pretty sure that there's a better way to do it with scikit learn. I am somewhat familiar with python but new to scikit learn. Please help.

What I want to do is follows:

A = f_A(a,b)

B = f_B(a,b)

What is supposed to happen in the system is when I input a==5,b==3 to the black box function, it needs to output A=5, B=3. But it outputs slightly different values like A==5.5, B==2.8.

I ultimately want to know the black box function f_A(a,b) and f_B(a,b). I assume that f_A(a,b) and f_B(a,b) are linear. For instance,

A = f_A(a,b) = a * w_Aa + b * w_Ab + constant_A

B = f_B(a,b) = a * w_Ba + b * w_Bb + constant_B

The cost is c = ((A-a)^2 + (B-b)^2)^0.5

So, I want to find w_Aa, w_Ab, w_Ba, w_Bb such that they minimize the cost function above. Anyone gives me an advice? Thanks in advance.

Comment: sklearn is not what you are looking for, scipy is

Comment: What do you mean by "it needs to output A=5, B=3"? If f_A and f_B are functions/estimators you train, then the predicted outputs are likely to be different from the true values. It looks like you want to train a `linear_regression` with a L2-norm. You can get the linear regression coefficients with the `coef_` attribute as shown [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html)